# HAProxy splitting read/write postgresql

Tags: postgresql, file-io, split, load-balancing, haproxy

I use postgresql as database. I have a master/slave with streaming replication. I want to use HAProxy for load balancing. I want to send the writes to the master, and the reads to the slave. Can I do this with haproxy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't. HAProxy doesn't understand the PostgreSQL protocol so it has no idea what "reads" or "writes" are.

Take a look at PgPool-II, which can do this to a limited extent. In practice it's usually better to configure the application so it knows to route its read-only queries to a different server if possible.

Answer (score 3):

We are doing it by defining a frontend for reading and other for writing, each one listening on different ports, and routing them to backends where you have your db cluster organized.

Example of HAProxy config:

```
frontend writes
    bind *:5439
    default_backend writes_db

frontend reads
    bind *:5438
    default_backend reads_db

backend writes_db
    option pgsql-check user haproxy
    server master_db ip.for.my.master:5432 check

backend reads_db
    balance roundrobin
    option pgsql-check user haproxy
    server replica_db ip.for.my.replica:5432 check
```

In our case, we use Django so we need to define the `routers` and `settings.databases` so all write operations are done on one port of the HAProxy server (5438) and all read operations are done on the other one (5439).

Comment: For Django users, you will have to be careful about routing since the official documentation is not very good. Any questions, here please.

Comment: Would do you specify the password for pgsql-check ?

Comment: You don't need it, since HAProxy doesn't even need to go through pg_hba.conf, but the server to only respond.